# Mean Average Precision with 11 points interpolation method Python libs

Tags: python, auc, interpolation, library, precision-recall-curve

I want to calculate mAP with 11 points interpolation method for object detection, as described here:

https://learnopencv.com/mean-average-precision-map-object-detection-model-evaluation-metric/

What Python libs do implement this algorithm?

For example, average_precision_score from sklearn doesn't seem to use 11 points interpolation...